# Javascript - call super on parents parent?

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-8, super

I have defined this extension of current custom javascript view in Odoo:

```
openerp.account_move_journal_test = function(instance){
    var _t = instance.web._t,
        _lt = instance.web._lt;
    var QWeb = instance.web.qweb;
    instance.web.account.QuickAddListView.include({
        init: function(){
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            console.log("QuickAddListView modified init")
        },
    });    
};
```

Now for better representation I added console log in `QuickAddListView` and in `ListView`, which are parents that are called using `_super`.

So if I run it like this, I get these prints:

```
'ListView init'  // This is parent of QuickAddListView
'QuickAddListView Init'
'QuickAddListView modified init'
```

The order of constructors is this `View` -> `ListView` -> `QuickAddListView`

So all of this is printed like it should, but what I want is to modify `init` in a way that it would directly call `ListView` and skip `QuickAddListView` original `init`.

So after that it should print only this (meaning original QuickAddListView init was not called):

```
'ListView init'  // This is parent of QuickAddListView
'QuickAddListView modified init'
```

Is there a way in javascript to specify exact parent you want to call? So instead of calling that everything is in a chain, it would start from where you specify (Like in my case from `ListView`)?

For example in Python you can do something like this:

```
from some_module import SomeBaseClass

class CustomBase(SomeBaseClass):
    def m1(self):
        super(CustomBase, self).m1()

class Custom(CustomBase):
    def m1(self):
        # skip CustomBase
        super(CustomBase, self).m1()
```

Comment: Where does `this._super` come from? This usually never works.

Comment: @Bergi what do you mean usually never works? It is builtin in Odoo to be used for inheritance to mimic inheritance/extending like for example in a Python.

Comment: Ah, [I see](http://odoo-master.readthedocs.org/en/8.0/howtos/web.html#classes), should be OK then. It only works when it's dynamically set during every method call, like it seems to be provided by your framework; this approach doesn't work with a constant `_super` on every instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way in javascript to specify exact parent you want to call?

Yes, you're pretty much already doing that: Using `this._super` to explicitly refer to `QuickAddListView`'s `init` method.

> So instead of calling that everything is in a chain, it would start from where you specify? And directly call `ListView` and skip `QuickAddListView` original `init`.

For that case, you'd only have to replace the line

```
this._super.apply(this, arguments);
```

by

```
instance.web.ListView.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
```

(or however you can access that class, not sure about Odoo)

But **be warned that this an absolute antipattern**. If you want to inherit from `QuickAddListView`, you should run its constructor (or `init` method) so that it can initialise the properties it needs. If you don't want that for whatever reason, you probably just should not inherit from it but inherit from `ListView` directly.

Comment: Well yeah it goes a bit against structure. But I want this, because there only few functions in QuickAddListView that I want to modify this way. For `init` I would rewrite some of the properties that are in `QuickAddListView`, but not all of them, because I need some to be skipped. But for other functions, those should function the same as in original `QuickAddListView`, so thats why I was thinking of doing this. I'll check your answer tomorrow, when I get back to my work PC.

Comment: I think you should rather call the `QuickAddListView`, and then manually unset/reset/refine the properties that you don't need or need to be different. That way it's much more explicit and obvious what you are really doing.

Comment: Well for `init` it is not a big deal. I could really call `QuickAddListView`. But for other methods (I mean functions) I need to modify, I don't see a way how can I do that. I mean if I would call it from `QuickAddListView`, then it would be too late. In other words it would do an action I'm trying to prevent. For example it would create/modify some record. But if I would call some function directly from `ListView` then I could rewrite specific action (that is meant to be done in `QuickAddListView`). Don't know if I explained it clearly.

Comment: Ah yes, for other methods it's not such a big deal.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and its working. So just if anyone would need this, you should change `instance.web.account.ListView.prototype.init.apply` to `instance.web.ListView.prototype.init.apply`, because thats the path to `ListView` `init`. And I'll accept your answer then.